# Looping through an array to return components that contain a bootstrap modal - React

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, modal-dialog

I have this function

```
renderInvoiceQuotes() {
    if (this.props.listOfInvoiceQuote) {
      return [
        <div className={styles.divContainingList}>
          {this.props.listOfInvoiceQuote.map((item, i) => {
            return (
              <div>
                <IVAPR key={i} current={item} />
              </div>
            );
          })}
        </div>
      ];
    }
  }
```

it return several `<IVAPR />` components

In the `<IVAPR />` component there is a normal bootstrap modal.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
  View
</button>


<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        {this.props.current.name}
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So several `view` buttons are being rendered just as expected, When I click a button I was expecting the `{this.props.current.name}` in each `modal` body to be the current `item.name`, however all the modals are being populated by the first item only. I do not understand this behavior. I was expecting when I click a button, the `{this.props.current.name}` to be populated by the `item.name` of the current `item`

Am really hoping this makes sense
the `item` being passed as a prop is an object in which one of the keys is name

Answer (score 0):

This may be due to that fact that each modal has the same id (assuming your template code above is correct (id="exampleModal") - try making each id unique

in effect if the id is the same - there may be several views, but the button click will be calling the same modal (`data-target="#exampleModal"`) - not a new instance of a new modal.